# Proving projective equivalence of Auslander Transpose

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $$P_1\overset{\partial}{\rightarrow} P_0\rightarrow M\rightarrow 0$$ be an exact sequence of $A$-modules with $P_0$, $P_1$ finitely generated and projective. The transpose $T(M)$ is defined as $\mbox{coker}\mbox{Hom}(\partial,A)$, after applying $\mbox{Hom}(-,A)$:
$$0\leftarrow T(M)\leftarrow P_1^*\overset{\mbox{Hom}(\partial,A)}\longleftarrow P_0^*\leftarrow M^*\leftarrow0$$
How does one show that $T(M)$ is independent, up to projective equivalence, on the choice of the projective resolution? Many books mention this fact but none of them seem to give a proof.

Comment: Any two projective resolutions are chain homotopic. Does this help?

Comment: @Rasmus $\mbox{Ext}^1(M,A)\subset T(M)$, but I don't see how isomorphism of $\mbox{Ext}^1(M,A)$ leads to projective equivalence of $T(M)$?

Comment: I haven't really thought about this, but here's a hint from Eisenbud's commutative algebra: reduce to the case where the comparison maps in two projective resolutions of $M$ are surjective.

Comment: @Theo Buehler Yes, I saw that hint, but as is often the case with Eisenbud, I don't see how that can be of any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer here:

http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9809121v2