# On Auslander transpose and stable Hom module

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, derived-functors

For finitely generated modules $M,N$ over a Noetherian local ring $(R, \mathfrak m)$, define $$P_R(M,N):=\{f\in \text{Hom}_R(M,N): \exists n\ge 0 \text{ and } M\xrightarrow{g} R^n \xrightarrow{h} N \text{ such that } f=h\circ g\}.$$  Then I can prove easily that $P_R(M,N)$ is an $R$-submodule of $\text{Hom}_R(M,N)$. So define $\underline {\text{Hom}}_R(M,N):=\text{Hom}_R(M,N)/P_R(M,N)$.

Now for a minimal free resolution $F_1\xrightarrow{d_1} F_0 \xrightarrow{d_0} M\to 0$ , we define the Auslander transpose of $M$ to be $\text{Tr}(M):=\text{coker}  \text { Hom}(d_1, R) $ (see [Proving projective equivalence of Auslander Transpose](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65066/proving-projective-equivalence-of-auslander-transpose)).  So $\text{Tr}(M)$ fits in an exact sequence $0\to M^*\xrightarrow{d_0^*} F_0^* \xrightarrow{d_1^*} F_1^* \to  \text{Tr}(M)\to 0 $

My question is:

> How to prove that
> $$\underline {\text{Hom}}_R(M,N) \cong \text {Tor}^R_1(\text {Tr}(M),N)\ ?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proposition  12.13 of Leuschke and Weigand's [Cohen Macaulay Representations](http://www.math.unl.edu/%7Erwiegand1/BOOK.pdf) has a proof of this for general commutative rings.